Error creating Ionic project on Windows with Ionic 7 and Node.js 20.12.0
I'm encountering an error while attempting to create a new Ionic project using the ionic new command. I've tried various troubleshooting steps but haven't been able to resolve the issue. Here are the details:
npm ERR! D:\test\node_modules\nx\src\native\index.js:244
npm ERR!     throw loadError
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: The specified module could not be found.
npm ERR! \\?\D:\test\node_modules\@nx\nx-win32-x64-msvc\nx.win32-x64-msvc.node
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1465:18)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
npm ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test\node_modules\nx\src\native\index.js:66:29)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v20.12.0

Steps taken

cleaning npm cache, reinstalling dependencies, checking
Node.js version compatibility

Environment:

Operating system: Windows 10 pro
Ionic version: 7
Node.js version: 20.12.0


You can start with checking if node_modules@nx\nx-win32-x64-msvc\nx.win32-x64-msvc.node physically exists. What are the exact steps to reproduce on your side from scratch? "reinstalling dependencies" - how exactly? This error could appear if OS or any of software versions mismatch, but currently it looks unreproducible. Otherwise nobody would be able to use it under the same conditions.

Sounds like a OS issue. Best bet is to remove node modules and re install.

I've been encountering the same issue even after repeating the steps multiple times and trying different Node.js versions. I've also attempted to format my laptop.
